# Wrap in select box - issues with Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have a bootstrap select box that has options that are too big for the width of the select container. The select has been overridden and styled accordingly. I have made it (or want it) to wrap the option text within the select box. It looks nice in chrome but FF it does not wrap. Take a look at http://bootply.com/83141

The work around for me would be to change the: text-overflow:''; to "ellipsis". Ellipsis still wraps in chrome but is more user friendly in FF by adding the ...

Does anyone have any alternatives or get FF to warp like chrome?

```
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="styled-select caret-select">
                    <select name="tickets" id="tickets" onchange="setContractValue();">
                        <option>this is a long option that needs to wrap in the box</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: One alternative is to create a whole new select manually using jQuery or something and a hidden field. So instead of an actual select tag you use maybe a list with a suckerfish dropdown style thing going on, with click handlers that set the value of the hidden form field depending on which LI you click. Obviously this is not an ideal situation as semantics are thrown out of the window, but it is a possibility is style comes before everything else. You can make it look however you like and aren't limited to the normal rules for select/options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try emulating a select tag with fieldset. See https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4563/editable_select.html

That or you can make two option tags. One is the first and the other is the continuation of the first. They both select the same value.

Otherwise it looks like you'll have to make something in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020 based on research there does not seem to be a solution, and your workaround to add an ellipsis in Firefox is the best I found.